# IRC Communication Details

Tags: c, irc

recently I read something basic about Socket Programming in C and, in order to practise this basic knowledge, I tried to write a programm, which just should do a little bit of conversation between the user and IRC Server.

Here is the relevant Code:

Initializing the Communication Socket:

```
void init(char *s[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    printf("%s : connect . . .\n",s[0]);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET,s[1],&server.sin_addr.s_addr);
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(s[2]));
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))!= 0)
        printf("%s : socket succesfully initialized.\n",s[0]);
    if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server))==0)
        printf("%s : succesfully connected.\n",s[0]);
}
```

Sending Messages:

```
void putmessage(char *s)
{
    write(sock,s,sizeof(s));
}

/*--------*/
(...)
    do
    {
        scanf("%s",input);
        putmessage(strcat(input,"\r\n"));
    }while(strcmp(input,"quit"));
(...)
```

Receiving Messagges:

```
char *getmessage(void)
{
    int i,t = 0;
    char *p1,*p2;
    p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1));
    *p1 = '\0';
    p2 = malloc(sizeof(*p2));
    *p2 = '\0';
    do
    {
         i = read(sock,buf,BUFSIZE-1);
         buf[i] = '\0';
         t += i+1;
         p2 = malloc(t);
         strcpy(p2,p1);
         strcat(p2,buf);
         free(p1);
         p1 = p2;
    }while(i == BUFSIZE-1);
    return p1;
}
```

which is just called infinitely after forking the process to use one for receiving and one for sending.
the communication works basically, because the messages i receive from the different irc servers i tried (irc.quakenet.org,irc.debain.org/com) were always errormessages related to the messages i sent, saying that I miss parameters.

Now my question is: why can i connect to those irc networks via a telnet client properly, but not with my own code using the same messages (PASS,NICK,USER). What things could be important for me, like the encoding(what encoding does the gcc genereally use?)?

The programm runs under Ubuntu 12.04. If you need further information, please ask.

Comment: Surely the "missing parameters" error reported to you should tell you what you are missing? Else refer to the IRC protocol, it should tell you how to construct your messages...

Comment: I read both related RFCs and my messages are exactly the same on my own code and the telnet client i used for testing. On the telnet client it works and on my own code it doesn't therefore i drew the conclusion that the problem is the connection and not exactly the form of the used messages

Answer (score 2):

Your client is not sending the entire messages of your input, because of the way you are trying to write on the socket file descriptor.

```
void putmessage(char *s)
{
    write(sock,s,sizeof(s));
}
```

The operator `sizeof` is not what you want to use in this case, because you will send `sizeof(char*)` bytes, which is the size of the pointer.

You should use something like `strlen(s)` instead.